# Browser Viewport detection with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, viewport

I am using plain JavaScript code to detect browser viewport and which is as follows:

```
function setLocation(url) {
   if (window.location.href.indexOf(url) === -1)
      window.location = url;
}

function reloadPage(width) {
    if (width < 701) {
        setLocation("layout700.php");
    } else if (width < 900) {
        setLocation("layout900.php");
    } else {
        setLocation("layout1200.php");
    }
}

var done = false;

function ready() {
    if(!done) {
        done = true;
        reloadPage(document.width);
    }
}

if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready, false);
    window.addEventListener('load', ready, false);
} else if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', ready);
}

window.onresize = function() {
    reloadPage(document.width);
};
```

**My question is :** How can I define width range in this?

What I mean is.... Is it correct if I use as

```
function reloadPage(width) {
    if (width <= 701 && >= 480) {
        setLocation("layout700.php");
    } else if (width <= 900 && >= 701) {
        setLocation("layout900.php");
    } else {
        setLocation("layout1200.php");
    }
}
```

**If this is not correct then what is the correct syntax? Kindly help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function reloadPage(width) {
    if( width >= 480 ) {
      if (width <= 701 ) {
        setLocation("layout700.php");
      } else if ( width <= 900 ) {
          setLocation("layout900.php");
      } else {
         setLocation("layout1200.php");
      }
   }
}
```

What is changed from your code ? 
- After the logical operator " && " you did not mention the variable name, which is incorrect. 
- You need not check for " width > 701 " in the second condition, because, if it was <= 701, the first condition would have been satisfied.

EDIT : Added a wrapper if() to check the page is greater than 480, since you don't have any layouts specific to that.

Comment: Just checkingout... Will post the result shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the largest and move to the smallest. Also, because setLocation should immediate halt execution, you can optionally leave out the "else" stuff. Finally, I assume if width is less than 900, you should go to layout700, even if the width is less than 700? It seems like it would be the closest-fit for a very thin browser.

```
if (width>1200) {
  setLocation("layout1200.php"); }
if (width>900) {
  setLocation("layout900.php"); }
setLocation("layout700.php");
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. My default size is 1200px and upto 960px I am controlling via css and fluid layout. However for Tablets, iPhones, Android Phones and further smaller screends, I want to server specific layouts and content. I am actually zero in Javascript and that is why I am having issues understanding the correct syntax. Can you please help me with the correct syntax depending on what I just mentioned in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to borrow this (http://adactio.com/journal/5429/) technique that Jeremy Keith has just blogged about and use the content attribute to store the correct page for the relevant dimensions - you could then use media queries to differentiate between the various sizes.

Something else you might want to consider... is using Device Atlas or 
WUFRL to detect the end users browser and serve them out the correct layout to start - redirects are poor experience for end users and particularly slow over mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, However the situation is like this: 1. I am developing an opem-source templating framework which must have a range of options to serve all types of browsers and perfection as close as possible. 2. Media queries are not supported by all browsers specially the old ones. 3. I am not re-directing the visitor here. I am actually serving a diferrent layout depending on his device. Lastly I think Device Atlas is a commercial solution, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Your setLocation method is effectively a client-side redirect.  If you apply a sensible default then even browsers that don't support media quies will work - as Bryan Rieger says "the lack of a media query is infact your first media query"